# TypeScript: how to serialize and deserialize object with different names via class-transformer

Tags: typescript, class-transformer

I have `User` object with `firstName` property. I want to deserialize it from `first_name` but serialize it as `firstName`.

My TypeScript code:

```
import { Expose, Exclude, classToPlain, plainToClass } from "class-transformer";
import "reflect-metadata";

@Exclude()
class User {
  @Expose({ name: "first_name", toClassOnly: true })
  firstName: string;

  constructor(s: Partial<User> = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, s);
  }
}

const user = plainToClass(User, { first_name: "Mari" });
console.log(user); // { firstName: "Mari" }

const plainSettings = classToPlain(user);
console.log(plainSettings); // { first_name: "Mari" }
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zyq1up)

I want `classToPlain` to serialize property as `firstName`. Using double `@Expose` ignores the second one:

```
@Expose({ name: "first_name", toClassOnly: true })
@Expose({ name: "firstName", toClassOnly: false})
firstName: string;
// the same behaviour
```

Is there way to serialize/deserialize object with different property names?

Answer (score 0):

***edited I just realized you were trying to change the name of a property. That is not something I can help with. I thought it was just class serialization/deserialization.

I just fought this battle for several days and I think I finally cracked it. Here is what is working for me with a sample user & address.

```
import * as clone from 'clone'
import Address, { AddressFactory } from './Address'
import { classToPlain, plainToClass, Type } from 'class-transformer'

export class User {

name: string
userID: string

@Type(() => Address)
address: Address

constructor(name: string, userID: string, address: Address) {
    this.name = name
    this.userID = userID
    this.address = address
}
copyObject(): User {
    return clone<User>(this)
}

getObjectForSaving(): Record<string, unknown> {
    return classToPlain(this)
}
}
export default User

export class UserFactory {
static fromVoid(): User {
    return new User('name', 'userID', AddressFactory.fromVoid())
}
static fromJSON(jsonObjectData: User): User {
    return plainToClass(User, jsonObjectData)
}
}
```

Then the Address Model

```
import { classToPlain, plainToClass } from "class-transformer"
import * as clone from 'clone'

export class Address {
    num: number
    street: string
    city: string
    state: string
    zip: number
    constructor(num: number, street: string, city: string, state: string, zip: number) {
        this.num = num
        this.street = street
        this.city = city
        this.state = state
        this.zip = zip
    }

    copyObject(): Address {
        return clone<Address>(this)
    }
    getObjectForSaving(): Record<string, unknown> {
        return classToPlain(this)
    }
}
export default Address


export class AddressFactory {
    static fromVoid(): Address {
        return new Address(0, '', '', '', 0)
    }
    static fromJSON(jsonObjectData: Address): Address {
        return plainToClass(Address, jsonObjectData)
    }
}
```

I use the factory functions for generating new objects. Can be a new default object or instantiate a new class instance with the static fromJSON constructor. You can also create additional factory constructors if you need them.

Last, I use the copy object to quickly copy objects when updating state in Redux to help with immutability etc...

Good luck!